# regex replace with optional whitespaces

Tags: .net, regex

Suppose I have special tokens like [DOT], [COMMA] and similar.  These can occur somewhere in a string.
Would it be possible to construct some regexp so it would replace them with an empty string and one of surrounding white spaces should be destroyed?  For example, 
"Mr[DOT] Drubber took his 12 [DONG] with him" should become "Mr Drubber took his 12 with him". 
So this code doesn't work:

```
string strToFix = "Mr[DOT] Drubber took his 12 [DONG] with him";
string templateWords = GetSpecialTokens(); // \[DOT\]|\[COMMA\] etc
string wrongString = Regex.Replace(strToFix, templateWords, "");
//wrongString becomes "Mr Drubber took his 12  with him"
```

Or it's not possible to construct such a regex replcace?
Thank you for consideration.

Comment: Would you always have whitespace specifically on one end or the other, in the edge cases where it isn't on both sides?

Comment: Good point.  It depends.  I now even consider situations like "My [DING] [DONG] string".

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\[(DOT|DONG)\]", "");
```